# How to append HTML to images using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, galleria

I am using [Galleria](http://galleria.aino.se/) and I need to wrap my images that Galleria puts into a slide with a link.

I was going to use this methodology: Give the `<img>` a bogus `title=` value and then append a `<a>` tag around the `<img>`, drawing the link I need from the `title=` tag.

This is the code I've got so far.

`$("img#gallery").this.title.appendTo("img#gallery") {  });`

I'm trying to get the script to loop through all of the images and append the html.

I also don't know if I should be using `.appendTo` or `.before` and `.after`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That approach will work.  You're looking for the wrap function:

```
var title = $('#test').attr('title');

$('#test').wrap('<a href="'+title+'" />');
```

This $.each will let you iterate through a series:

```
<img src="" class="test" alt="test" title="http://www.google.com" />
<img src="" class="test" alt="test" title="http://www.yahoo.com" />

$.each($(".test"), function() {
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    $(this).wrap('<a href="'+title+'" />');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just listen for a click on the entire thing and then figure out if an image was clicked and if so which image and then change the location object.

Comment: I understand the theory, but what are the functions that would execute that?

Answer (score 0):

Use $.each to iterate through all the images you want to wrap and then use

```
$('img#gallery').wrap('<a href='whatever'>)
```

to wrap it. It will automatically close the A tag.